# Using cloves in stocks/broths

Tags: stock, ingredient-selection, turkey

I have a (somewhat) recently purchased spice jar of cloves in my pantry that isn't getting much attention.  I've seen stock/broth recipes that call for whole peppercorns, and am curious if subbing cloves would create a different/unique taste profile, or if it will just ruin the stock.   Curious for input on how best to use these as I have some leftover turkey from a pre-Thanksgiving trial run I did and was planning to make the drumsticks/carcass into a stock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most chicken (or turkey) stock recipes are meant to be fairly neutral in flavor so they can be used in almost any dish.  In many culinary traditions, especially those of European tradition, black pepper is appropriate in almost any savory dish.

Cloves are an extremely strong and aggressive flavor, which is not traditional in these cuisines.

While you could certainly use it in your stock, it would give that warm clove aroma, and you would then want to use the stock only in dishes where that is appropriate.

Instead, I would stick to neutral flavors, and if you want clove flavoring, do it when preparing the final dish, not he fundamental stock.   You can simmer enough stock for the whatever dish you are making with a few cloves while you are doing your prep on the dish to infuse it, if needed.